# Laravel upload image from Javascript given an image URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I have an image URL in javascript extracted from a canvas in html and i want to create an image from that URL and upload it to my storage files in server.
i can send the Url in a ajax post request to my sendImagetoController function in controller or if there is a method from javascript  to do that.My routes are all defined and tested.Please Help
my display.blade.php .

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HeatMap Display</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <script src='http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/assets/js/heatmap.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/heatmap.js' )}}" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script>
            var coordinatesarray = @json($coordinates);
            var finalcoordinatesarr=[];
            var count=0;
            var mapId={{$targetHeatMap->id}};
            var mintime=10000000;
            var maxtime=0;
            var imgUrl="";
            coordinatesarray.forEach(element => {
                var cor={
                    'x' : coordinatesarray[count]['x'],
                    'y' : coordinatesarray[count]['y'],
                    'value' : coordinatesarray[count]['time_spent']  
                };
                if(mintime>coordinatesarray[count]['time_spent']){
                    mintime=coordinatesarray[count]['time_spent'];}
                if(maxtime<coordinatesarray[count]['time_spent'])
                    maxtime=coordinatesarray[count]['time_spent'];

                finalcoordinatesarr.push(cor);
                count++;                           
            });

            console.log(finalcoordinatesarr);
            function load(){
                renderCanvas();
            }

            function renderCanvas(){
                var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
                container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
                });
                var testData = {
                        min: mintime,
                        max: maxtime,
                        data:finalcoordinatesarr
                };
                heatmapInstance.setData(testData);
                imgUrl = (document.getElementById("heatMap").childNodes[0]).toDataURL();
                document.getElementById("heatMapPic").src=imgUrl;
            }
            sendImageToController();


            function sendImageToController(){
                formdata = new FormData();
                if($('#heatMapPic').prop('files').length>0){
                    file = $('#heatMapPic').prop('files');
                    formdata.append("heatMapPic",file);
                }
                formdata.append('tagetHeatMap',$('#targetHeatMap').val());
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } 
                    });
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('HeatMap.moveToStorage')}}",
                    data: formdata,
                    type:'post',
                    // traditional:true,
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log("correct");
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error:function(e){
                        console.log("errrooooor");
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                });
                console.log("hi");

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
        <input type="file" id="heatMapPic" name="heatMapPic" src=""/>
            <input type="text" id="targetHeatMap" value="{{$targetHeatMap}}"/>
        </form>


            <div id="heatMap" style="height:740px"></div>
                <a-scene>
                    {{-- <a-sky radius=10 opacity="0.8" src="{{asset('uploads/heat_map_images/'.$targetHeatMap->heatmap_image)}}"></a-sky> --}}
                    {{-- <a-sky radius=10 src="{{asset('uploads/'.$imageName)}}"></a-sky> --}}

                </a-scene> 

            </body>
</html>
```

my Controller method

```
  public function moveToStorage(Request $request){
        return 'hello';

        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual problem is? Your controller is clearly not handling POST requests yet, are you asking how to do that?

Comment: right now the method am using to store image in storage  isnt working (it isnt even reaching the controller to return hello) and am looking for a method to either save my image from javascript or send my url as text to controller and do the work there

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to send the image *before* it is actually rendered. You need to move `sendImageToController()` inside your `load` function, after `renderCanvas()`. Also, no need for all the formData stuff. Just send the result of `.toDataURL()` as-is to the server, then use `base64_decode()` to turn it back into an image.

Answer (score 0):

If you have url which is publicly accessible then you can use it like this

```
public function moveToStorage(Request $request){
      $data = $request->all();
      $url = $data['file_url'] ; //file url that you have in javascript
      $contents = file_get_contents($url);
      $name = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
      Storage::put($name, $contents); 

      return 'hello';
}
```

> OR if your file is posted as base64 then try this

```
public function moveToStorage(Request $request){
      $data = $request->all();
      $file = $data['file_url']; //base64 encoded image
      $file = substr($file, strpos($file, ",")+1);
      $imgeData = base64_decode($file);
      $contents = file_get_contents($imgeData);
      Storage::put("test.png", $contents); 

      return 'hello';
}
```

Comment: hi i tried this but got stuck with :    "message": "file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty", error .Just to clarify the imageUrl am sending from display.blade.php to contoller moveToStorage is merely a string URL not a file

Comment: are you sending the file url ? check it printing `$data`. dd($data) and the url should be accessible

Comment: yes i tried printing(dd) the data and Url ad they are reaching now the controller

Comment: what is the filed name ?

Comment: u mean what i want to name myimage in the storage ? anything test.png for now. Or URL var :imgUrl

Comment: i mean filed name `file_url` should be posted from javascript code

Comment: @SandyAlAkhras better you print out `$data` and check does it has `file_url` filed if exist then check does it has a complete url or base64 image and then use any one of these answer. i think you can send the base64 image that will work too

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in PHP, the fact that the file itself comes to php through the variable $_FILES() and is not visible in the main query.

```
<?php
    putenv("upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/site.com/public_html/upload/");
    $uploadDir = getenv("upload_tmp_dir");
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile);
?>
```

Then you can open the file in the path in the $uploadFile variable

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to send the image *before* it is actually rendered. You need to move `sendImageToController()` inside your `load` function, after `renderCanvas()`.

Also, no need for all the formData stuff. Just send the result of `.toDataURL()` as-is to the server, then use `base64_decode()` to turn it back into an image.

Here are the relevant changes:

```
function load() {
  renderCanvas();
  sendImageToController(); // send to server AFTER rendering
}

var imgUrl;

function renderCanvas() {
  // ...
  imgUrl = (document.getElementById("heatMap").childNodes[0]).toDataURL();
  // ...
}
```

Shorter AJAX code:

```
function sendImageToController() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  $.post("{{route('HeatMap.moveToStorage')}}", {
      heatmap: imgUrl  // global var set in renderCanvas()!!
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      console.log("correct");
      console.log(response);
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
      console.log("errrooooor");
      console.log(e);
    });
}
```

On the server, grab the `heatmap` parameter.

```
public function moveToStorage(Request $request){
  $heatmap = $request->input('heatmap');
  $base64 = explode(",", $heatmap)[1];
  $binary = base64_decode($base64);
  // store $binary data in PNG file
  return 'image saved successfully';
```

}